# Выделить в текущей строке всё с первого непробельного символа до последнего

Tags: vim

Допустим, у меня есть строчка кода с отступом

```
         promocode.discount_amount
```

и курсор где-нибудь в районе слова `discount_amount`.

Чтобы выделить всё важное на строке, например, для заворачивания в скобки, я набираю

`$v^`

Уверен, есть более быстрое решение, но никак не могу его найти.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Поправка: чтобы переместиться к последнему непробельному символу, надо использовать `g_`, а не `$`.

В вашем примере сработает <kbd>v</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>W</kbd> (**i**nner **W**ORD, см. `:help text-objects`). Однако, в общем случае, когда в середине строки могут встречаться пробельные символы, это работать не будет. К сожалению в Vim нет стандартного text-object-а для того, что нам нужно.

Тут нам на помощь придут mapping-и. Будем использовать для нашего «объекта» буквосочетание `il` (**i**nner **l**ine). Никто не мешает использовать один символ, но тогда скорее придется пожертвовать соответствующей стандартной командой. Следующий mapping для visual mode позволяет сделать то, что нам нужно:

```
:vnoremap il :<c-u>normal! ^vg_<cr>
```

Теперь при нажатии <kbd>v</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>l</kbd> будет выделена «важная» часть строки.

Опционально: сейчас `il` работает только в visual mode. Можно заставить его работать со всеми командами Vim, которые ожидают на вход movement или text-object (`d`, `y`, `c`, и т.д.). Для этого используются mapping-и для Operator-pending mode (см. `:help omap-info`):

```
" внимание, в правой части используется mapping il, который мы определили выше
:onoremap il :normal vil<cr>
```

Теперь, в частности, <kbd>y</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>l</kbd> копирует «важную» часть строки, а <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>l</kbd> — удаляет ее.

Подробнее почитать, как и почему это работает можно в:

- Главе [Operator-Pending Mappings](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/15.html) (и след.) в книге [Learn Vimscript the Hard Way](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/)
- Статье [Creating new text objects](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Creating_new_text_objects)
- Стандартном `:help`

Comment: Ценное замечание про `g_` — я истребляю все пробелы на конце строк, поэтому совершенно забыл, что кто-то может быть к ним вполне толерантен. Спасибо за ответ, примерно как-то так я себе это и представлял, но думал, что объект «строка» всё-таки в VIM есть.